# How to use old printer as wireless

Tags: windows-10, router, android, network-printer

I have a Samsung SCX 4321 series printer and it connects using a usb. I also have Huawei router (EchoLife HG8145V5) that has a usb port, so help me to make my printer wireless and accessible from all my devices.

I have USB 2.0 and IEEE ports on my printer.

P.S. - My printer does not support wireless and ftp settings. Its just a basic wired printer.

Comment: What model Huawei router?

Comment: My solution requires purchasing nothing.  Windows supports "Printer Sharing".. this is most likely the easiest solution.  Any old junk windows pc can do this so you won't need to use your primary.  Enable (and setup) printer and file sharing on the PC.  Once setup properly, "Google Cloud Print" and other windows machines should be able to find the printer on your network.

Comment: So did you just try yet? If so, where exactly did you get stuck? // Google Cloud Print is going away in less than 6 months.

Comment: ***Hold up a minute.. ??*** .. Does that printer not have an ethernet port on the right side next to the USB port?  As pictured [here](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c05786810)?  If it is the SCX-4321NS, it certainly does.  And this is actually a rebranded HP printer.

Comment: I have updated my router model in the question. And my printer is only SCX 4321 not that NS version of it, so I think it has different ports.(Updated question with ports)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get a wireless USB Hub  (there are many of these).  Set up the Wireless on your network and attach the Printer to the USB Hub.

Reinstall the Printer Driver to be sure it picks up the printer.

Here is a general Tutorial to assist you. Google for one of the many such hubs.

https://www.net-usb.com/usb-over-wi-fi/wireless-usb-hub/

Here is a New Egg suggestion for purchase.

https://www.newegg.ca/p/pl?d=wireless+usb+hub

A benefit of this approach is that no particular computer needs to be ON and any computer with the driver can print.  This is very handy in my environment

Comment: So, if the whole point is to not spend money on another printer, why would he do this?  This solution costs almost as much as buying a printer that supports wireless printing.

Comment: @Sheersh Jindal - I agree about reducing costs.  Please be alert to the possible economy of purchasing a printer that is network ready.  This may be more economical over the medium run. I always prefer networked printers over shared printers (based on my own experience over the years).

Comment: I think that his printer IS network ready.

Comment: Sorry, I would have tried that usb hub thing but out of funds currently, and I am on my home network so I think network or shared printer would not really matter here.